# Form Fields on mobiles are not clickable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, z-index

Here is the website: http://www.hotelsunlimited.tech/
Here is the code I think have problem. Problem is when on small screens, clicking on request a demo, fields are not clickable...
I guess the problem is somewhere about z-index. I tried almost all posts/methods, but could not solve it.

```
<div id="requst_demo" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- modal content start -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-gray">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
          <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="requestDemoDisplay"><!-- <i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"> --> Request Demo</h5>
         </div>
        <div class="modal-body_bg col-md-12">
        <div class="contact contact-us-one">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center mb20">
        <h4 class="pb25 bb-solid-1 text-uppercase">
        Help us to Reach You
            <small class="text-lowercase">Please complete the form and we will get back to you.</small>
        </h4>
        </div>
       <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted){$('#inputInfo').hide();$('#requestDemoDisplay').hide();$('#successMessage').show();}"> </iframe>
      <form name="contactForm" id="ss-form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/17hNuB00okyMsEvvNrirQCZzZtwEEGmF1trFfBIwvKgI/formResponse" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true" method="POST">
      <div id="inputInfo">
      <!-- fullname start -->
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="entry.301789256" id="entry_301789256" class="input-md input-rounded form-control" placeholder="Fullname" maxlength="100" required="">
       </div>
       </div>
       <!-- fullname end -->
<!-- email start -->
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="entry.1752605527" id="entry_1752605527" class="input-md input-rounded form-control" placeholder="Work Email-ID" maxlength="100" required="">
</div>
</div>
<!-- email end -->
    <!-- textarea start -->
<div class="col-sm-12">
<textarea class="form-control" name="entry.1630854875" id="entry_1630854875" placeholder="Any Question" rows="7" required=""></textarea>
</div>
<!-- textarea end -->

<!-- button start -->
<div class="col-sm-12 mt10 text-center">
<button type="submit" value="Submit" name="sendMessage" id="sendMessage" class="button button-md button-block button-grad-stellar">Send Message</button>
                </div>
                <!-- button end -->
                  </div> <!---end of inputInfo-->
           <div id="sendingMessage" class="statusMessage sending-message">
           <p>Sending your message. Please wait...</p>
           </div>
           <div id="successMessage" class="statusMessage success-message">
           <p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>
           </div>
           <div id="failureMessage" class="statusMessage failure-message">
           <p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>
            </div>
           <div id="incompleteMessage" class="statusMessage">
           <p>Please complete all the fields in the form before sending.</p>
                    </div>
            </form>
         <div id="successMessage2" class="statusMessage success-message">
         <p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>
                                        </div>
                        </div><!-- div contact end -->
                    </div><!-- col end -->
                </div>
                <!-- modal content end -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the following changes in inspector and they did the trick, let me know if you have an issue with them.

Add the following css

```
.modal-dialog, .modal-content{height: 100%;}
```

The above line fixes the appearance but not the text input issue.
The following line will fix the input box not responding

```
#inputInfo .col-sm-12{clear: both;}
```

This is because the column that contains the textarea below is extending above its limits to cover the first two input fields.

Comment: Great. It worked For Request Demo. I have same issue with Join Now, could you please check that too?

Comment: I am waiting on you sir. @mohammed Alsaedi

Comment: Hi I just noticed your comment @HamidSheikh I will get back to you with an answer later today.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also check this page: http://hamidsheikh.net/iphone/index2.html I am trying to make the iframe responsive. It shows responsive when I see on the laptop, but is not responsive on the mobile (I am checking it on iPhone).                                                           <iframe src="https://survey.zohopublic.com/zs/JhDXp6" width="100%" height="700">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>